# string split does not split [0].Property by the dot

Tags: c#, string, split

```
string[] array = indexAndProperty.Split(new char['.']); // [0].PreCondition
```

Why has the array only one element with string `"[0].PreCondition"`?

I expected it to split the string by the dot and get 2 elements `"[0]"` and `"PreCondition"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`new char['.']` does not create an array with one character, `'.'`. Rather the `'.'` is coerced to an `int`, and the integer equivalent of `'.'` is 46, so it actually creates an array with 46 copies of `'\0'`.

Try this:

```
string[] array = indexAndProperty.Split(new char[] { '.' });
```

Or better yet, because the `separator` parameter of [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) is a [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) array, you can just do this:

```
string[] array = indexAndProperty.Split('.');
```

Answer (score 3):

`new char[x]` creates an array of *x* empty `char`s.

You want to create an array of a single `char` containing `'.'`:

```
new char[] { '.' }
```